# Log Out Destroy CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, logout, destroy

Why can't I destroy the session when I log out?

My Auth Controller

```
public function index(){
    $this->data['page_title'] = "User Login";
    $this->load->view('templates/master', $this->data);
}

public function login(){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $data = $this->User_model->login ($username, $password);
    if($data){  
    $this->session->set_userdata('users', $data);
    $session_data = array(
        'username' => $username);
    $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
    redirect('users');


    }
    else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata
        ('loginfail','<div class="alert alert-danger"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <strong>Danger !</strong> Invalid Email or Password .</div>');
       return redirect("auth");


    } 
}

public function logout()
{
    $this->session->unset_userdata(array('username','id')); 
    $this->session->sess_destroy(); 
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($this->session->all_userdata()); 
    exit; return redirect("auth");

}
```

My PHP:

```
<a href="<?= base_url('auth/logout')?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logoutModal">
    <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
    Logout
  </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 <?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
      class Auth extends MY_Controller {

    public function index(){
        /* You Should check Session before loading page */
      if(empty($this->session->userdata('id'))){
         redirect('users');
       }    
        $this->data['page_title'] = "User Login";
        $this->load->view('templates/master', $this->data);

         }
    public function login(){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $data = $this->User_model->login ($username, $password);
        if($data){  
        $this->session->set_userdata('users', $data);
        $session_data = array(
            'username' => $username);
        $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
        redirect('users');


        }
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata
            ('loginfail','<div class="alert alert-danger"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
            <strong>Danger !</strong> Invalid Email or Password .</div>');
           return redirect("auth");


        } 
    }
    public function logout()
    {
        $this->session->unset_userdata(array('username','id'));
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect("users");

    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this but still not working. huhuhu i cant figure out why this is not working.

Comment: check the session datas are cleared or not print_r($this->session->all_userdata());

Comment: $this->session->unset_userdata(array('username','id'));
  $this->session->sess_destroy();
  $this->session->all_userdata();
                 return redirect("auth");

Comment: $this->session->unset_userdata(array('username','id')); $this->session->sess_destroy(); echo '<pre>'; print_r($this->session->all_userdata()) exit; return redirect("auth");

Comment: theres an error Message: syntax error, unexpected 'exit' (T_EXIT)

Comment: $this->session->unset_userdata(array('username','id')); $this->session->sess_destroy(); echo '<pre>'; print_r($this->session->all_userdata()); exit; return redirect("auth");

Comment: Array
(
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1583400399
)

Comment: there's showing an array

Array
(
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1583400399
)

Comment: what this mean?

Comment: but it doesn't redirect to the log in page , it just showing on page itself.

Comment: i updated my auth code at the top with your code in logout function . that's my whole auth code.

Comment: theirs weird happening , the page is still loading

Comment: i dont figure out whats happening but . the problem now is i cant proceed to my login page when i click logout button, it will redirect to my users list page which is the users

Comment: when i tried to change to redirect to auth it the site is loading.

Comment: where you load your login page

Comment: on auth controller , that's my login page

Comment: yah think this is it the session completely destroy but i when i try to click the back button it will go to the page again. .